# Does anyone know of any Android coded example of facebook's scrolling tiles?

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-layout, android-activity

Within Android, I'd like to create a Facebook scroll like effect, where I can place text on each tile and a user can scroll through the information.

There is a Facebook screenshot below, is there any chance anyone knows of any coded examples on-line which could help me out? Thanks

[image]

Comment: this is just a list like anything else (although Facebook likely created their own ListView for performance reasons). each row has a card or tile. I would suggest learning how to use ListView (or ideally, the new RecyclerView) as well as the new CardView support library from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CardView. See the [android developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView) about it, it contains an example. Hope this helps

Comment: That's true, changed it.